# How to play multiple videos?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
<iframe class="play01" width="603" height="339" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ovxVLRBB7Gk?rel=0"&vq=hd1080></iframe>

<iframe class="play01" width="603" height="339" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gfedLRBB7Gk?rel=0"&vq=hd1080></iframe>

<iframe class="play01" width="603" height="339" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gwertRBB7Gk?rel=0"&vq=hd1080></iframe>
```

Is it possible to use one iframe to play all videos in chain ? When first video finished, the second automatically starts and so on ?

Comment: off topic because: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: @AndyHolmes, do you meen I need to create a composite merged video from these three ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a youtube playlist and then read this article for some code to help you out - http://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-youtube-playlists/17687/

Probably the easiest way!

Comment: No problem :) If it is the correct answer please accept when you have tested etc :) Thanks!